# Как очистить кэш браузера через javascript?

Tags: javascript

Есть страница, при заходе на которую у пользователя страница должна грузиться с сервера,
а не из кэша. Можно ли очистить кэш через javascript? Или заставить страницу грузиться с сервера, не используя кэш браузера?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно заголовки HTTP добавить:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.
```

Обычно все сразу добавляют, чтобы точно не кэшировалось.

Comment: Эти заголовки запрещают кэширование? Получается, что если человек уже был на сайте, то браузер сохранил в кэш скрипты, стили и т.п., и эти заголовки бесполезны?

Comment: @Виктор Павлов
Думаю да, т.к. ресурс уже закеширован брузером и фактического запроса на сервер не происходит.

Для того чтобы обойти эту проблему, обычно добавляют ничего не значащий параметр (соответствующий, например, номеру версии приложения на сервере), таким образом избегая кешироания.

Пример

    http://mydomen.ru/js/script.js?v=345874954

Если в качестве параметра будет рэндомное число, то кеширования не буде вообще никогда, несмотря на заголовки.

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov, @Виктор Павлов  Думаю, нет. Если в конфиг сервера прописать ваши заголовки или ограничиться конкретно assets (css, js, gif,...), то сервер будет отдавать незакэшированные данные.

Пример для nginx:

    location ~* \.(js|css|ico|xml|swf|flv|eot|ttf|woff|pdf|xls|htc)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";
    }

Для выборочной статики Вы всё верно написали: `http://mydomen.ru/js/script.js?v=345874954`

Comment: @romeo, там не в сервере дело, а в браузере.

Если когда-то стояло приложение на сервере, которое эти заголовки не проставляло, то до тех пор пока кэши браузера не сбросятся, будут отдаваться закешированные скрипты. Они из кэша браузера браться будут.

Comment: @romeo, ну а если GET'ом параметр передать, то очевидно кэширования не будет.

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov 

>там не в сервере дело, а в браузере.

Очевидно, что нормальный браузер реагирует на заголовки сервера.

![alt text][1]

> ну а если GET'ом параметр передать...

Вся статика таким образом и передаётся.

[1]: http://i.imgur.com/azSf1wx.png

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov, иногда кэш даже в этом случае проходит и заголовков для всякого случая добавляют шесть:

    Header("Expires: Thu, 19 Feb 1998 13:24:18 GMT");
    Header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    Header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    Header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    Header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
    Header("Pragma: no-cache");

Comment: >> Очевидно, что нормальный браузер реагирует на заголовки сервера.
@romeo, а я и не говорил что заголовки ответа не обрабатываются.

@Alex Krass, интересно как это будет работать больше чем один заголовок *Cache-Control*.

Заголовок *Last-Modified* нужен для запроса *If-Modified-Since*, отношение к клиентскому кэшу иметь не должен.

Comment: на самом деле ещё бывает кэш на прокси (причем в некоторых случаях достаточно жесткий), в таком случае можно сделать XHR запрос с заголовками Pragma и Cache-Control

Answer (score 4):

Помогло линкование скрипта с параметром

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js?ver=12345">
```

При этом если изменить версию напр.(ver=12222) - браузер подгружает обновленный скрипт с сервера, а не берет из кэша.

Comment: Это тоже хорошо, но вопрос был всё-таки про страницу, а не про скрипт

Answer (score -1):

Лучше включить управление кэшем веб-сервера. Необходимо настроить сервер таким образом, что бы тот передавал один из заголовков: `Last-modified`, `Etag`, `Expires`, `Cache-control`.

Полное отключение кэша, увеличит бесполезную нагрузку на сервер.