# Обновление скриптов и стилей без нажатия CRTL+F5?

Tags: javascript, css

Есть скрипты и стили подключаемые к сайту. Имеют вид `site.min.*(css|js)`. Как сделать так чтобы при изменении этих файлов у пользователей сайта они были всегда в актуальном виде. Не прибегая к комбинации клавиш <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>? Есть вариант не использовать php?

Comment: отправлять их по WebSocket

Comment: Да. Каждый раз при сборки бандла в конце всех нужных url в html документе нужно написать `?рандомный_набор символов`, например `/js/index.js?2339501439`. Но обычно этим занимается либо сам php либо плагины к вебпаку в момент сборки. Это самый лучший вариант имхо, ибо нет головных болей с мета-тегами и прочей ерундой. Полезная ссылка http://max22.ru/bx-solutions/versionnost-js-i-css/

Comment: На пыхе как-то так `<script src="js/scripts.js?v=<?php echo filemtime('../js/scripts.js') ?>"></script>`

Comment: @Дмытрык поясните как?

Comment: По таймеру с каким-нибудь интервалом (раз в сутки, или как частоту времени обновлений деленную на 2 по теореме Котельникова. Короче, эдадкий хартбит, или пинг) ) проверять версию стилей и при изменении версии обновлять страницу.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin А можно скриптом сбросить кэш броузера?

Comment: @doox911 есть такой вариант https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/401260/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d1%8d%d1%88-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-javascript

Comment: или сразу в `html` прописать `<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin задал вопрос и потому, что может кто предложит что-то более современное)

Comment: Вообще-то, это вполне современной решение ) Если английским владеете, то вот мужички обсуждают с 2011 года и по сей день
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache

Comment: а где в вопросе о кэше что-либо говориться? Если речь о кэше, то это дубликат. Ссылку давали выше

Comment: @Дмытрык а где броузеры хранят ранее загруженные скрипты или стили?

Comment: слово "актуальные", имеет иное значение, чем "ранее загруженные". У меня открыт Ваш сайт - Вы поправили стили.. у меня в браузере актуальные стили или нет?... как передать мне актуальные стили без Ф5?

Comment: @Дмытрык не уже не актуальные.  А как проверить что они отличаются от не изменённых (которые были загружены ранее)?

Comment: По WebSocket прислать сооббщение об обновлении стилей, и на кленте, через JS, либо обновить страницу, либо каким-либо другим способом применить новые стили